# C# MVC LocalResource on Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-storage

I have this line of code that uses the Azure.ServiceRuntime.LocalResource class:

```
LocalResource localResources = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource(fileName);
```

When I tried to access the controller that has this line it gives me the following error (not the specific action in the same controller), essentially a 403 error:

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

I am not sure if this how it should work on Microsoft Azure with my C# MVC5 application. I have also tried adding an Azure storage account (Storage Account - blob, file, table, queue) but it still didn't work. The file that I am trying to create is a pdf file.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LocalResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.localresource.aspx) Class remarks:

> A local storage resource is a reserved directory in the file system of the virtual machine in which an instance of a role is running. To define a local storage resource for your hosted service, you must add a LocalResources element with LocalStorage elements to the ServiceDefinition.csdef file of the hosted service for each directory that you want to create.

So if you want to use  RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource method to get the path, you must add a LocalResources element with LocalStorage elements to the ServiceDefinition.csdef file of the hosted service for each directory that you want to create.

But if you want to want to add the created pdf file to the azure storage account's blob file.

You need use the storage library to to do this.

You need firstly create a pdf file in your server, then you could upload the file to azure storage account(for example: blob).

More details about how to upload the file by using storage account library, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#upload-a-blob-into-a-container).